# Why is the UK Corporation tax payment deadline before the company tax return filing deadline?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, accounting, small-business, business

I've returned to contracting (as a software engineer) after 8 years of full time employment and am now working through my own LTD company.

I mistakenly thought - as is the case with self assessment - that my corporation tax payment deadline would be the same date as the company tax return filing deadline, but was surprised to find that it's actually 3 months earlier.

At first glance it seems odd that payment would be required before you're actually required to calculate your tax liability for a financial year, but I'm presuming there's a reason behind this (...that google has been unable to shine any light on), can someone please explain why this is the case?